# PFFile keeps returning nil although data is logged and image is set

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimagepickercontroller

For some odd reason I keep getting a crash when attempting to save a PFFile to Parse. I know that there is an image because the passengersPhoto is being set to it, and imageData is being set because I printed it in console. The issue is when it gets to this line.

```
profileImg!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in
    if success {

    }
})
```

I get the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" I'm not sure how profileImg is nil when there is imageData clearly if both the passengersPhoto is being set and imageData is printed.

FULL CODE:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.passengerPhoto.image = image

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    let profileImg = PFFile(data: imageData)

    profileImg!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if success {        
            self.passengerPhoto.image = image
        }
    })    
}
```

Comment: what does `print(imageData)` log ?

Comment: bunch of scrolling sets of data